# Stirling’s approximation and Big O

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

How to prove that $2n \choose n$ = $\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(1 + O(1/n))$ using Stirling’s approximation?

I know how to prove that $2n \choose n$ = $\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ but I am having trouble with the prof of big O.

Any help Would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You know how to prove ${2n\choose n}={2^{2n}\over\sqrt{\pi n}}$?? Then what do you need the big-oh for?

Comment: What version of Stirling's approximation are you using? Does it include a big-O term? If it does not, check your notes and see if you have forgotten to copy a big-O term from somewhere. In any case, _edit the exact formula of the approximation into the body of your question_. The question is incomplete without that. (And also indicate anything else you have figured out about this problem, so we don't waste time telling you something you already know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Stirling's theorem
in the form
$n!
=\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n(1+O(1/n))
$.
This will give you
the $O(1/n)$
that you want.